# Can a shadow sorcerer see in darkness created by another shadow sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, vision-and-light

I have a party with 2 Shadow Sorcerers. If one of them casts *darkness* with sorcery points, is there a way - RAI or RAW it doesn't matter- for the other sorcerer to see through it?  It seems stupid that a shadow sorcerer can't see through a spell cast with his own capacity.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you review the linked question and see whether it matches yours?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [feature description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic):

> **Eyes of the Dark**
>
> Starting at 1st level, you have darkvision with a range of 120 feet.
>
> When you reach 3rd level in this class, you learn the darkness spell, which doesn't count against your number of sorcerer spells known. In addition, you can cast it by spending 2 sorcery points or by expending a spell slot. **If you cast it** with sorcery points, **you** can see through the darkness created by **the spell**.

The description is pretty clear that whomever uses the sorcery points is the one that can see through the darkness. There is no provision for seeing through any other magical darkness.

Also note, that the sorcerer can only see through the *darkness* spell that they cast. They cannot expend two points to see through someone else's darkness spell, regardless of origin.

Answer (score 3):

### Unfortunately you can't do this without a houserule

The Eyes of the Dark feature states:

> [...] When you reach 3rd level in this class, you learn the *darkness* spell, which doesn't count against your number of sorcerer spells known. In addition, you can cast it by spending 2 sorcery points or by expending a spell slot. **If you cast it** with sorcery points, **you can see through the darkness** created by the spell.

It only applies to a *darkness* spell which you yourself cast, that said you could ask your GM (or houserule) that this *does* work for the *darkness* spell cast by *any* Shadow Sorcerer using sorcery points (though this is quite specific). This may somewhat step on the toes of the the Warlock's Devil's Sight Invocation which states:

> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

The overlap between these features is so incredibly small/niche that it may not matter in the long run.

Personally, I believe a houserule allowing any Shadow Sorcerer to see in magical darkness made by the *darkness* spell cast by another Shadow Sorcerer that used Sorcery Points in the casting is likely so specific it won't have very much balance implications outside of the convenience it grants to your party. If this does prove to be overly strong, the houserule can always be reverted.